# Getting null pointer exception while compiling via netbeans but same source code works in another class

Tags: java, netbeans

under generated code am getting an additional line of generated code like

```
 query1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null :  ((javax.persistence.EntityManager)null).createQuery("");
```

Am not able to delete this. how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: `((javax.persistence.EntityManager)null).createQuery("")` are you sure that this is working in another place ?

Comment: this is created in one class automatically i dono why it is added but in another class it is not there so only that is working

Comment: Have you tried clicking on it and pressing Ctrl+E?

Answer (score 1):

The else  part contains `((javax.persistence.EntityManager)null).createQuery("")`, which throws NPE.

Change that to appropriate instance of `EntityManager`